# Want to know if a certain class implements an specific interface

Tags: java, reflection

I have a program that asks the user for a `String`, which should be the name of a class that implements the `Message` interface.

All the java classes are in package `ist.ap.labs`

The code is this one:

```
Class cl = null;

try {
    cl = Class.forName(className);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException clnfe) {
    System.out.println("Class not found!");
    System.exit(1);
}

if (!cl.isAssignableFrom(ist.ap.labs.Message)) {
    System.out.println("Class not implements Message!");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

But I always get an error saying `cannot find a symbol:class labs`

Any help?

Comment: Look into `class` literals.

Comment: If your question involves a compiler error, always please show us your exact and full error message.

Comment: I suspect that `!ist.ap.labs.Message.class.isAssignableFrom(cl)` is what you want...

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonSkeet, you solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to refer to the class literal, not only the class name:

```
if (!cl.isAssignableFrom(ist.ap.labs.Message.class)) { ... }
                                          //  ^ Here
```

EDIT: And, yes, Jon Skeet got it right once more in the comments: You have to swap `cl` and `ist.ap.labs.Message.class` to perform the desired test.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
        Class<?>[] interfaces = Child.class.getInterfaces();
        List list = Arrays.asList(interfaces);
        if(list.contains(Interface.class)){
            System.out.println("true....");
        }
```

This would say you whether the class implements the interface.